# This code shows error "stu undeclared"?? what should i do

Tags: c++, arrays, testing, dynamic

I know this error is because i have declared stu inside the for loop scope but its the necessity of the program.I want to declare an array for each test case (test case should all be input at once).Suggest me a way to achieve this.Is dynamic memory an alternative.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    int n[t],g[t];
    int m =0;
    for(int w=0;w<t;t++)
    {
        cin>>n[w]>>g[w];
        int stu[n[w]];
        for(int i=0;i<n[w];i++)
        {
            cin>>stu[i];
        }

    }    
    while(m<t)
    {
        int a,b;    
        int e;
        e = (n[m]*(n[m]-1))/2;
        int diff[e];
        if (g[m]=1)
        {
            cout<<0<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
        b=*(min_element(stu,stu+n[m]-1));
        a=*(max_element(stu,stu+n[m]-1));
        if (g[m]=n[m])
        {
            cout<<a-b<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
        int z = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<(n[m]-1);j++)
        {
            for(int k=(j+1);k<n[m];k++)
            {
                diff[z]=abs(stu[j]-stu[k]);
                ++z;
            }
        }        
        cout<<*(min_element(diff,diff+e-1))<<endl;
        ++m;
    }    
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you said try to use dynamic memory allocation and declare the stu outside the for loop

Comment: Dynamic. Memory. Allocation.

Comment: stu[n[w]] is for creating an array for diffrent value of n in test cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `stu` inside of a `for` loop, so it is limited to the scope of the loop. You then try to use it outside of the loop, where it is undeclared.

```
for(int w=0;w<t;t++)
{
  ...
  int stu[n[w]]; // Beware: stu is a VLA. Non-standard C++.
  // OK to use stu here
  ...
}    
// stu doesn't exist here
```

Also note that standard C++ does not support [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLAs), which is what you are attempting to use in the declaration of `stu`, as well as here:

```
int t;
cin>>t;
int n[t],g[t];
```

You can replace these arrays by `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int t=0;
  cin>>t;
  std::vector<int> n(t);
  std::vector<int> g(t);
  std::vector<int> stu ...;

}
```

Comment: (I suppose it is supported as extension by g++?)

Comment: @ShinTakezou Correct, it is a GCC extension, which can be disabled with strict compilation flags.

Comment: seen it, just tried with `-pedantic`, and updated the answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Thank you sir.Since i am just a beginner can you please tell me what is a vector and how it is different from other data structures?

Comment: @KartikKhare You are welcome. Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: ya now i get it.
but still i am stuck with one problem.now the code after modification
runs infinitely and never gives output.It continues to take input as long as we want it

Comment: @KartikKhare in that case you should post a short code sample that reproduces the problem. But it may be better to do so in another quesition, since it seems like an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int stu[n[w]];
```

is inside a block and outside that block it won't be seen. You should move it out of the block, but doing so of course you can't use `n[w]`, being w the looping var. You coudl put a limit to the max value `n[w]` can have, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const int MAXV = 100;
int main()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  int n[t],g[t]; // <- supported by some compiler, but not std
  int m =0;
  int stu[MAXV];
  for(int w=0;w<t;t++) {
      cin>>n[w]>>g[w];
      for(int i=0;i<n[w] && i < MAXV;i++) {
        cin>>stu[i];
      }
  }    
  while(m<t) {
      int a,b;    
      int e;
      e = (n[m]*(n[m]-1))/2;
      int diff[e];
      if (g[m]==1) {
        cout<<0<<endl;
        return 0;
      } 
      b=*(min_element(stu,stu+n[m]-1));
      a=*(max_element(stu,stu+n[m]-1));
      if (g[m]==n[m]) {
        cout<<a-b<<endl;
        return 0;
      }
      int z = 0;
      for(int j=0;j<(n[m]-1);j++) {
        for(int k=(j+1);k<n[m];k++) {
          diff[z]=abs(stu[j]-stu[k]);
          ++z;
        }
      }        
      cout<<*(min_element(diff,diff+e-1))<<endl;
      ++m;
  }    
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

(I've fixed a couple of assignment in conditional when I suppose you meant `==` and not `=`, but I've not tested if the code does what you expect: it just compile, with g++ but not with other compiler likely, see comment in code)

Comment: (g++ with option `-pedantic` gives errors because of variable-size arrays)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...and its running fine on my compiler

Comment: But after inputting the values for first test case won't it overwrite the values already stored in the array for latter cases